# Does PySpark to_date() method simply truncates a datetime to a date?

Tags: datetime, pyspark

I wanted to use the [`to_date()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date) method on some UTC datetime records to keep only the date part of it.

All it does is a truncation or it does something else? I need to know that because I don't want my UTC datetime to be converted to some other time zone (eg. the one of the server).

So, is that safe to use with UTC datetimes without risking a timezone conversion?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it won't do a timezone conversion. It will only give you a `datetime.date` object which is not timezone aware.

Comment: Thank you! Do you also have a source to back that up? I looked at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#to_date but I don't get the reference to the java method...

Comment: No, man. I am speaking out of experience here.

Comment: Ok fair enough, thanks!